# Response.redirect with text

Tags: express, http, if-statement, redirect, response

Let's say I have a function which ends with a response.redirect('/'). How can I parse a message along which is shown on that path? Here is a breift example:

```
expressApp.post("/test", function(request, response) { 
 if (user) {
            response.redirect('/')
        }
}
```

There is more to the function but this is enough for the question here. How can I parse a message or some text to the path "/" and display it in my view?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to pass on data (messages) through redirections other than the use of **sessions**. You need to set variables in the sessions and access them in another page. For simplicity, these messages are referred to as **flash messages**. You can use flash messages using the module **express-flash**. There are solid tutorials on Google and everywhere else, they should be highly helpful.

Your code when using express-flash:

```
expressApp.post("/test", function(request, response) { 
    if (user) {
    req.flash('mymessage','hello from route');
    response.redirect('/');
    }
})
```

In another route file, simply use

```
expressApp.post("/", function(req,res) {
    res.send(req.flash('mymessage')); // Will show "hello from route"
})
```